# MIT 6006 Quiz 2: The shortest path task

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I'm looking for some clarifications on an algorithmic task I've been trying to solve. This task is a part of Quiz 2 from the [MIT 6.006 course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/exams/).

The main idea of creating `k`-copies of a graph `G` is clear. What I'm really confused with is the final graph `G'`:

- Can you explain how the graph `G'` will look like?
- How will the `G'` graph guarantee that all of the places `{v0, v1, v2, vi}` had been visited once we reached the destination vertex `t`?

I'm sorry if the community to post this question is wrong. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

[Input](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/exams/MIT6_006F11_quiz2_sol.pdf):
[image]

[Solution](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/exams/MIT6_006F11_quiz2_sol.pdf):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think here is how it should look like. You duplicate the graph `G` as many times as many `v` places you have to visit (e.g. `v0`, `v1`, `v2`). The order you must visit these vertices is the constraint which is expressed as zero weight edges (G1.v0 -> G2.v0, G2.v1 -> G3.v1).

[image]